# C++: Converting the resultset of a SQL query into JSON

Tags: c++, sql, mysql, ajax, json

Is there a standard way/well known method to convert the results of a SQL query, using the MySQL client library, or otherwise into JSON so I can directly pass the results to a JS script?

Before the obvious, no, I'm not allowing SQL queries directly from the browser, I'm implementing a specific subset of SQL in a simple API to expose to clients who will be retrieving the results using AJAX, I figured JSON is the best encoding, just wanted to check and see if there was already a well known way of doing this before I wrote my own.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at:
http://weblogs.asp.net/thiagosantos/archive/2008/11/17/get-json-from-sql-server.aspx
It provides a recipe to get JSon from SQL. 
My the way, I assume that it is MS SQL as you don't specify.
Good Luck